# Can random elements be defined in terms of a measure algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebras

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space, $(X,\mathcal{X})$ be a measurable space and $R(\Omega,X)$ be the set of equivalence classes of measurable functions from $\Omega$ to $X$ under almost everywhere equality, they are *random elements*. Let $(\mathcal{A},\mu_A)$ be the [measure algebra](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Measure_algebra_%28measure_theory%29) of $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$, that is $\mathcal{A}$ identifies elements of $\Sigma$ if their symmetric difference has outer measure zero and $\mu_A$ is defined in the natural way in terms of its representatives.

> I would like to know if one can
>   identify the elements of $R(\Omega,X)$
>   with something that can be canonically
>   be constructed in terms of
>   $(\mathcal{A},\mu_A)$ and
>   $(X,\mathcal{X})$.

The motivation behind the question is the following: I work with certain random elements that are defined on a countably generated probability space. By [Maharam's theorem](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1078424/), this amounts to the measure algebra being isomorphic to one that consists of a convex combination of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and a discrete probability space. I would like to know whether it makes sense for me to say that I'm essentially working with such a probability space.

Comment: Perhaps this calls for consideration of the *Image measure catastrophe* ... http://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=image+measure+catastrophe 

Comment: @Gerald: could you please summarize the image measure catastrophe in a comment?